# What Time of the day are the maximum users using puzzling S.E?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, data-dump

> Is there any data about what time there is maximum people visiting puzzling S.E ?
>
> This data may be on views of a question that is posted at a particular time of the day.

Comment: Suggested edit: replace 'Time' with 'time'.  Move the period from in between SE to repplace the space. And remove the quote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a picture where the points are connected more aesthetically.

Link: http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/522760/when-people-are-online#graph

[image]

Comment: So, which standard time is it?? GMT??

Answer (score 2):

Here is a graph:

[image]

You can find the info at a data query here: http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/145483/when-people-are-online#graph

So it looks like the peak is at 2:00PM, UTC time.

Comment: is time GMT?...

Comment: @AmruthA I think so.

Comment: The points are joined interestingly...